# How to activate button handler on ctrl+click?

Tags: r, button, handler, gwidgets

How can I activate a `gbutton()` handler on <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd> in `gWidgets2`?

Consider the following code:

```
w <- gwindow("Buttons")
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

b2 <- gbutton("ouvrir", cont=g)
b4 <- gbutton("click me", cont=g)
h4 <- function(h,...) {
    if(svalue(b2) == "open")
        svalue(b2) <- "ouvrir"
    else
        svalue(b2) <- "open"
}
addHandlerChanged(b4, h4)

h4bis <- function(h,...) {print("hello world on ctrl+click")}
```

So what I would like to achieve is:

- When clicking on the `b4` button, the `h4` handler gets activated (as it does now)
- When control + clicking  on the `b4` button, the `h4bis` handler gets activated

How can I do this?

Comment: In `gWidgets2RGtk2` the `...` part of the event handler gets passed the values passed to the Gtk handler. In this case, there is nothing passed back. You would need to bind to a different event than `clicked`. Likely `button-press-event` will work, but then you give up activating the button by the keyboard.

Comment: In this case I don't mind giving up activating the button by the keyboard. So how would the `button-press-event` approach look like?

Comment: I haven't tested, but `btn$add_handler_button_release(function(h,w,e,...) {})` should pass in the `e` variable a `GdkEventButton` (https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventButton) which can be queried to check for modifiers like ctrl ('GdkModifierType').